# Make all values after a label have the same value of that label

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 2)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Which generates the following frame:

```
   col1  col2
0     6     3
1     7     4
2     6     9
3     2     6
4     7     4
```

I want to replace all values from row 2 forward with whatever value on row 1. So I type:

```
df.loc[2:] = df.loc[1:1]
```

But the resulting frame is filled with nan:

```
   col1  col2
0   6.0   3.0
1   7.0   4.0
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
4   NaN   NaN
```

I know I can use `fillna(method='ffill')` to get what I want but why did the broadcasting not work and result is NaN? Expected result:

```
   col1  col2
0     6     3
1     7     4
2     7     4
3     7     4
4     7     4
```

**Edit:** pandas version 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

I believe `df.loc[1:1]` is just the empty array, hence converted to `NaN`? It should be `df.loc[2:, 'Value'] = df.loc[1, 'Value']`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `df.loc[1:1]` actually returns a data frame of a single row. `df.loc[1, 'Value']` works because it returns a scalar. I have more than 1 column in my actual data frame so `df.loc[1, ['col1', 'col2']]` produces a series, which cannot be broadcasted.